# Wait for PID to exit using AppleScript

Tags: macos, process, applescript

I'm new to AppleScript but I have to recreate a batch file which I have written for Windows in OSX and AppleScript seems the best way to do this. Basically, the script will created by another program dynamically and then executed. The AppleScript simply needs to wait for a process, which I want to identify by its process ID, and display a message if the process is still running after a specific amount of time.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to my given problem after searching online a bit more. Here is the AppleScript code I use to check if a process with a given id `pid` is running

```
tell application "System Events"
    set runningApplications to (unix id of every process)
        if (runningApplications contains (pid as integer)) is false then
           -- process is not running
        else
           -- process still running
        end if
end tell
```

This is just a snippet obviously. Personally I have the above the statement in a `repeat` loop, but this offers a solution to checking a process id (which is the `unix id`).

Hope this helps others

Comment: Just a quick note (and thanks for the upvote!): It is good practice to use tell blocks only when necessary (for performance reasons). For example, I might do what you did this way: `tell application "System Events" to set runningApplications to (unix id of every process)` (notice the 'to') -- then leave the rest on its own (remove the 'end tell'). This uses the 'tell' only in that line.

Comment: Incidentally, sorry if I didn't make it clear that the 2nd bit of code (ps/grep/awk) in my initial msg does get the pid.

Comment: @CRGreen Thanks for the note(s). With regards to the PID, I only get the PID of *all* processes so that I can determine whether the PID of my application (which I can obtain) exists. This is the only way I could find to determine whether a specific PID exists easily using AppleScript

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to (hopefully) get you on your way:

- *shell scripts in terminal, and 'do shell script' command*: don't know how well you know Unix, but you definitely want to go there, and
  learn basics of bash. with some limitations, you can run shell
  scripts via AS through the 'do shell script' command.
- *writing the script dynamically*: osascript and osacompile will probably come in handy. see the man pages. osascript can execute
  scripts or script text, and osacompile can (!) compile text into
  script form (non-text form), among other things.
- *script waiting for/watching process*: more shell script stuff, or using the Finder (what used to be called the Scriptable Finder!),
  that is, the Finder's scripting capabilities (dictionary), like
  **tell application "Finder" to get name of processes**. The shell version (which can be called via the 'do shell script' AS command)
  might be **"ps ax | grep Safari | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'"** (taken from
  stackoverflow post. I like it because it returns empty string if no
  match).  Depending on how your main script will run, learn how the
  idle handler works in a script application, and how that differs from
  using an xcode-built app (if that's the route you go), or just a
  script.
- *displaying a message*: 'display dialog' is the super simple method, complete with timeout ("gives up" after n seconds). (Sorry if this is
  so basic I just insulted your intelligence :-) )
- *other*: Check out (unless you're already wedded to a script editing environment) Smile. It's my primary script editor.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. You have not insulted my intelligence, I am new to OSX, let alone AppleScript, so your answer is extremely useful to me. I did actually find a solution myself, which I will add here, but if I could up vote your answer more I would